# Parse the inner html tags using jSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to find the important links in a site using Jsoup library. So for this suppose we have following code:

```
<h1><a href="http://example.com">This is important </a></h1>
```

Now while parsing how can we find that the tag a is inside the h1 tag?

Comment: Have you seen http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax? If yes then you probably tried something already, so can we see your attempts to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Elements headlinesCat1 = doc.getElementsByTag("h1");
for (Element headline : headlinesCat1) {
    Elements importantLinks = headline.getElementsByTag("a");
    for (Element link : importantLinks) {
        String linkHref = link.attr("href");
        String linkText = link.text();
        System.out.println(linkHref);
    }
}
```

Taken from the [JSoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Use selector:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("h1 > a");
```